# What was the precursor of testosterone?

Tags: proteins, endocrinology, molecular-evolution

Testosterone evolved about 500 million years ago ([says 8fact.com](http://8fact.com/p/aWWl7q/)). What was the precursor of testosterone (if any)? If possible, what caused the 'precursor' to evolve?

Comment: This question is very vague and I am unsure if you are really familiar with how sex hormones work. Why would testosterone prioritse sex *per se*? What have you already learned about the functions of testosterone in the (presumably human) organism? What hypotheses do you have based on that knowledge? Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: Testosterone drives sex drive and has a role in starting puberty and producing sperm. How could that not encourage sex?

Comment: Organisms that do not produce testosterone do also produce sperm. Testosterone is definitely not needed for sexual reproduction at all. For me this question does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, but that is not my point. It still has a role in sex, does it not?

Comment: Just because you do not understand my question doesn't mean you should downvote it. I have put a lot of effort into editing, which by the way got rid of the question you didn't understand.

Comment: If you ask a precise and understandable question I will remove the downvote for sure. As is, I do not see any informative discussion coming out of a question as vague as this (no reference for the fact, what do you mean by precursor?, how could one - even theoretically - know what this precursor was? this is not how evolution works, the reason for evolution of a more than 500 MY old precursor is more a matter of opinion than fact, the relationship between the function of testosterone in the human body and sexual reproduction, ....) which in my view qualifies for a downvote.

Comment: If you do not know the answer, don't answer. It's that simple. No one forced you to answer so don't pull out that excuse. The word precursor is the analogue of ancestor, and only part of my question is (possibly) opinion based so there is no reason to dismiss it. Testosterone plays a major part in the sexual development of human males such as driving libido (sex drive), starting puberty and producing sperm. Just tell me how that is not related to sex. Answer my questions before you continue adding more to your argument.

Comment: Please add a citation that people can actually *read*. Your link simply redirects to what appears to be an advertisement for an app called Cookie, which I do not intend on even looking at, let alone downloading. There are plenty of web sites out there.

Comment: It says right on the page now linked in your question that testosterone developed from estrogen. So what's your question?

Comment: Someone else added that on and I did not know that existed so that know makes my question obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Biology.SE

The question suggests that you have important lack of knowledge in Biology (which is fine). It will be impossible to explain everything in a post. I therefore just provide a short answer and redirect you to some source of knowledge that will be necessary to read for you to really be able to understand the basis of molecular biology and evolutionary biology.

**Short Answer**

> Testosterone cannot 'evolve' per se because it is a hormone, right?

Testosterone is a chemical that is synthesize by our body. This synthesis is regulated by proteins which are coded in our DNA. The sequences in our DNA that code for proteins is called a gene (quickly speaking).

So, a mutation in a gene (or in a regulatory sequence) can impact the synthesis of testosterone and therefore be under selective pressures.

> Was it to prioritise sex and in turn pass on your genes?

I don't understand what you mean by "prioritise sex". But yes, those individuals making efficient synthesis of testosterone and good use of this signalling molecule had/have a higher fitness.

> Did the evolution of testosterone happen because of sexual reproduction?

Testosterone is directly used for sexual dimorphism, so in this sense it evolved in its current form because genders exist. However, the evolution of hormone synthesis (and related biochemical pathways) do not require sexual reproduction (asexual reproduction being the alternative).

**Source of Information**

I will recommend free online resources.

You should start with a basic understanding of the cell machinery. Make sure to really understand what DNA, RNA, proteins are and their relationship. I recommend [Khan Academy > Biology](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology). It is a long series of video, so I particularly recommend series on the so-called (and poorly called) [central dogma](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/gene-expression-central-dogma).

Then you might want to have a look at [Understanding Evolution (by UC Berkeley)](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01), which is a very introductory course on evolutionary biology.

Comment: I know about translation and transcription but I do not think you get what I am saying. Firstly, you did not answer my main question 'how did testosterone come to be?' and secondly, how exactly does my question demonstrate a lack of knowledge?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood indeed. I thought you had an important lack of knowledge and you seemed to not understand the relationship between DNA and the synthesis of a hormone. Can you please further what you mean by "how did testosterone come to be?". For the moment this question is very unclear to me. Are you interested in the precursor of the current form of testosterone?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am essentially looking for the precursor of testosterone. Plus, I edited my question to make it short and concise.

Comment: I would advice that you edit the post to specifically say something like "Testosterone evolved about 500 millions years ago (citation). What was the precursor of testosterone (if any)?". For the moment, the expression "How did testosterone come to be?" is still unclear IMO.

Comment: I have edited the post now, thank you for your contribution and help. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you please add the link to 8fact?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41318/discussion-between-mobal-and-remi-b).